# The stackapps icon is missing in the global logout page

Tags: bug, status-completed, logout, stackapps, favicon

I just visited [the SE logout page](https://stackexchange.com/users/logout) and it seems that the stackapps icon is missing:

[image]

This doesn't seem to affect site specific logout pages:

[image]

[image]

This seems to be because the site specific logout pages uses this image:

[Super long, link only](http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/favicons-sprite16.png?v=9845267392e422feae5471dd46c8df6c)

but the network wide logout page uses this http://cdn.sstatic.net/mathoverflow/img/favicon.ico

And stackapps uses some other URL that wasn't updated.

It doesn't load: https://stackexchange.com/content/stackapps/img/favicon.ico

It should actually update and use this: http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackapps/img/favicon.ico

Answer (score 2):

Now the stackapps icon is displaying correctly in the [SE logout page](https://stackexchange.com/users/logout).

Currently the each icon in this page is loading from the CDN path, So for the stackapps icon it is loading from [this path](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackapps/img/favicon.ico) with the success status.

[image: Stackapps favicon loading correctly]